# The requested resource not available in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn spring mvc and facing a problem (which seems to be a common one). I have searched a lot of solutions but nothing is helping me out...

My web.xml is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Spring Hello World</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>chatbooster</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>chatbooster</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My chatbooster-servlet.xml is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd


  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

When I try to run hello.jsp, the error is the requested resource is not available.

Hello.jsp:

```
   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="i" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     
 <html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Hello World!</h1>

 <hr/>

  <form action="hi">
   Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

HelloWorldController.ava

```
 @Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

@RequestMapping("/")
 public String hello() {
 return "hello";
 }

@RequestMapping(value = "/hi", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String hi(@RequestParam("name") String name, Model model) {
 String message = "Hi " + name + "!";
 model.addAttribute("message", message);
 return "hi";
}

}
```

Edit1:

The problem is occurring because of tomcat server as my simple html page is also not running and it is throwing the same exception. I am using tomcat server version 7. Can anyone hint me out the cause of this exception?

Comment: What kind of error do you get exactly? Is your controller being initialized? Does your controller method get called? People are also more willing to answer if you would accept some answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Sorry for that..I will keep that in mind. Regarding this problem, it seems the problem is related to the tomcat server as even simple html page is showing the same error when run by the server. Can you suggest me something what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat doesn't know about hello.jsp since it is inside WEB-INF.

Change

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

to

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a the case of Hello.jsp.  The first letter of Hello.jsp is capitalized yet in your controller you are returning a lower case hello.  If you change your controller to return the string "Hello" it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your answers. Actually I was able to solve my issue by just changing the location of html and jsp pages from web inf folder to web content folder. I dont know why it worked but pages are being run by the server now.